# Use XSLT variable in external css stylesheet

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have a file called `general.xsl` which contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="p-size" select="'20'" ></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="main-title-size" select="'36'" ></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="list-item-size" select="'22'" ></xsl:variable>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then I have `html.xsl` file, which includex my external `ppt.css` file and also contains for example paragraph template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ppt.css"/>
.. some code...
<xsl:template name="p" match="p">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, in my `ppt.css` I want to use variables `font-color` or `p-size` from `general.xsl` file (lets say in general.xsl, I have defined all variables needed), but it doesn't work this way:

```
p{
    color:{$font-color};
    font-size:{$p-size}px;
}
```

What needs to be changed?

Comment: You can't use xslt variables in an external stylesheet. XSLT does not process this css file at all. It is merely outputting a `link` tag in an html document, which will be processed by a browser. By the time the browser processes it, the XSLT process will be long gone.

Comment: @TimC so then I have to use only inline css?

Comment: Yes, you could use xslt variables if you were generating inline css in the `<style>` tag.

Comment: As you use XSLT 2 (at least the `version="2.0"` suggests that) you might also be able to use XSLT code to generate the CSS file as a secondary result document with e.g. `<xsl:result-document href="ptt.css" method="text">p { color: <xsl:value-of select="$font-color"/>}; ...</xsl:result-document>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use variables in CSS files you should take a look at **CSS preprocessors** like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide).

With this kind of tools you can maintain "dynamic CSS templates" and generate static CSS files out of it.

Then you can simply assign static style-names to elements in your XSL code.